# .click not working for <p> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know when a paragraph element has been clicked. I get no response when clicking p elements with this code.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Practice Extension</title>
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p style= "color: red">red</p>
    <p style= "color: blue">blue</p>
    <p>black</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery

```
function main() {
    $("p").click(function () {
        alert("a p has been clicked!");
    })
}
$(document).ready(main());
```

Comment: This code is working for me. What is in the file `popup.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(main());
```

Use

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

`main` is a function, and `$(document).ready` expects a function as a parameter. If you pass it `main()` instead of `main`, you are passing it the result of calling the function (`undefined`) instead of the function itself.